# 'CspKeyContainerInfo' requires Windows Cryptographic API (CAPI), which is not available on this platform

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, rsa, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2

I have upgraded my project to asp.net core v2.2 from v2.1 and everything was used to work just fine.In the code shown below, I am trying to initilaize an RSA Key for with IdentityServer4(v2.3.2) and while trying to get a token I get the following error.

```
        try
        {
            var rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

            var rsaParametersPrivate =
                RsaExtensions.RsaParametersFromXmlFile(Configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings:rsaPrivateKeyXml")
                    .Value);
            rsaProvider.ImportParameters(rsaParametersPrivate);
            var securityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsaProvider);
            _signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);

            _logger.LogInformation("InitializeRsaKey() successfully executed.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exception = new Exception("Identity Server RSA Key initialization failed. " + ex);
            _logger.LogError(exception, "InitializeRsaKey() method failed.");
            throw exception;
        }
```

> 'CspKeyContainerInfo' requires Windows Cryptographic API (CAPI), which is not available on this platform. error.

Also, my project runs on a CentOS machine meanwhile I develop my project on Windows 10. So, I am aware that something existing in Windows is missing on Linux. To solve the problem any help and suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I digged some github issues and found out that `RSACryptoServiceProvider()` intherits `ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm` and this class is supported only on Windows. For details check out [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17410#issuecomment-288774684). To fix the problem I have replaced `var rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);` line with `var rsaProvider = RSA.Create(2048);` and it works fine with .NET Core v2.2 on CentOS. Hope this helps those who have the same issue.

Comment: @konzo Glad it helped you.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion on a Docker Container running on Linux and it worked like a charm.